# SSMS Query - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, ssms

I'm receiving an error in the query below. The Sub-query works as it should; 3 columns, ID, Type, Amount. I'm having an issue with the Pivot Syntax, according to SSMS "near the keyword 'FOR'".

The query is mirroring a question in SO, and I see a ton of other similar questions but I can't seem to find the issue. I've tried using brackets, eliminating the Joins in the sub-query and joining after the data is pivoted but nothing has worked so far.

```
SELECT
dboBillingAdjustments.CMSId
,DataPivot.Certification
,[DataPivot.Contractor Supplement]

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Businesses.CMSId
            ,BillingAdjustments.Type
            ,BillingAdjustments.ContractorAmount

FROM BillingAdjustments
            JOIN BillingAdjustmentTypes on BillingAdjustmentTypes.Id = BillingAdjustments.TypeId
        JOIN Businesses on Businesses.UId = BillingAdjustments.BusinessId

    WHERE 
        DateKey = 20171104 AND
        IsSettled = 1

) as dboBillingAdjustments

PIVOT
(
    BillingAdjustments.ContractorAmount FOR Type in ([Certification], [Contractor Supplement])
) as DataPivot
```

Comment: You need `aggregation function` there, eg: `MAX(BillingAdjustments.ContractorAmount) FOR Type in ...` [see syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot)

Comment: That did it. Now that I think about it, that's exactly what a pivot is for. I wasn't understanding the syntax. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `PIVOT` you need an aggregation function `MAX(),MIN(),AVG()...`
for example:

```
PIVOT
(
    MAX(BillingAdjustments.ContractorAmount) 
    FOR Type in ([Certification], [Contractor Supplement])
) as DataPivot
```